# Using Saxon and XSLT to transform JDOM XML documents

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon, jdom

I'm trying to convert some XML so that iso8879 entity strings will appear in place of characters. For example the string `1234-5678` would become `1234&hyphen;5678`. I've done this using character maps and the stylesheets found at http://www.w3.org/2003/entities/iso8879doc/overview.html.

The first part of my xslt looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:import href="iso8879map.xsl"/>  
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration = "yes" use-character-maps="iso8879"/>
```

When I run this stylesheet in Eclipse with the Saxon XSLT engine it works fine and outputs an XML file with the hyphen entitiy string in place of the hyphen character. However, I need to automate this process so am using the JDOM package. Unfortunately, the characters are not being replaced during the transformation. The code that does the conversion looks a little like this:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
    "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");  // use saxon for xslt 2.0 support


SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
builder.setExpandEntities(false);       
XSLTransformer transformer = new XSLTransformer(styleSheet);

Document toTransform = builder.build(Fileref); // transform
Document transformed = transformer.transform(toTransform);
```

I then write the document out to a file using the following method:

```
public static void writeXMLDoc(File xmlDoc, Document jdomDoc){

    try {
        Format format = Format.getPrettyFormat();
        format.setOmitDeclaration(true);
        format.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter(format);
        //outputter.output((org.jdom.Document) allChapters, System.out);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(xmlDoc.getAbsolutePath());
        outputter.output((org.jdom.Document) jdomDoc, writer);
        writer.close();
    } 
    catch (java.io.IOException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've started debugging in Eclipse and it looks like the hyphen character isn't being replaced during the xslt transformation. I've tested this using the Saxon xslt engine on it's own and it does work, so it's likely something to do with using it from Java and Jdom. Can anybody help?

Many thanks.

Jim

Comment: Character mapping is not done in the transform, it's part of the output serialization, so you may not see them changed in the transform. It is JDOM that serializing your output, not Saxon.

Comment: "I need to automate this process so am using the JDOM package"... the latter isn't a conclusion dictated by the former. Saxon works, so why not automate the process using Saxon?

Comment: Indeed, if there's a good reason for using JDOM you can use it with Saxon. JDOM uses the XSLT 1.0 Xalan processor when you use its XSLTransformer API, but Saxon will also accept JDOM documents as input, allowing you to use XSLT 2.0 character maps.

Comment: @Micheal - I thought that by setting the system property in the line `System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
    "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");`  I was setting which XSLT engine TrAX uses?                                                                                                                                   @Steven It appears that the <xsl:output> tag is being ignored as JDOM is adding the XML declaration when I've told the XSLT engine to omit it. Would using an outputter other than JDOM's XMLOutputter help? Thanks.

Comment: @Michael - I've just found your JDOM Example from the Saxon SourceForge site. It shows using a Saxon wrapper around a JDOM document before passing it to a Transformer. Could this be where I'm going wrong? Currently I'm only using the home edition so am just supplying the Transformer with an unwrapped JDOM document.The transformation still happens but the xsl output instructions including the omit-xml-declaration = "yes" and use-character-maps="iso8879" seem to be ignored.

Comment: @JimS: xsl:output attributes are hints that are passed onto the serializer in a stand-alone XSLT processor. When you are using a JDOM tree as input and output to xslt engine, xsl:output is ignored. You are doing the serialization yourself with XMLOutputter. I don't know JDOM library very well, so I don't know what options you can control on output, but that's where you have to do it. Alternatively, you may be able to call SAXON's serializer with the right options to get the output you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem did turn out to be with not using the JDOM wrapper class provided by Saxon. Here's the working code for reference that shows a JDOM document being transformed and being returned as a new JDOM document:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");  // use saxon for xslt 2.0 support
File styleSheet = new File("filePath");

// Get a TransformerFactory
System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
                   "com.saxonica.config.ProfessionalTransformerFactory");
TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
ProfessionalConfiguration config = (ProfessionalConfiguration)((TransformerFactoryImpl)tfactory).getConfiguration();

// Get a SAXBuilder 
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder(); 

//Build JDOM Document
Document toTransform = builder.build(inputFileHandle); 

//Give it a Saxon wrapper
DocumentWrapper docw = new DocumentWrapper(toTransform,  inputHandle.getAbsolutePath(), config);

// Compile the stylesheet
Templates templates = tfactory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(styleSheet));
Transformer transformer = templates.newTransformer();

// Now do a transformation
ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);                  
transformer.transform(docw, new StreamResult(outStream));

ByteArrayInputStream inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outStream.toByteArray());
Document transformed = builder.build(inStream);
```

Comment: This is from Michael Kay:  "That's the documentation for Saxon 9.0. Do you really want to download Saxon 9.0? It's available if you have a good reason, but it's way out of date - for example, the JDOM support is for older versions of JDOM. For Saxon-B, look on SourceForge, for Saxon-SA it will be on the Saxonica site though no longer actively listed.

In recent releases JDOM support is bundled in Saxon-PE and higher; for Saxon-HE if you really want JDOM support you can download the source code and compile it."

So just be aware that this is code for an old version of Saxon.

Comment: If you want the current way to do this, download the additional resources file, which has a JDOM example:  http://www.saxonica.com/download/download_page.xml

Comment: The above code will still work fine Saxon 9.5, but the way you install the necessary support libraries has changed since 9.0. Since 9.2, the JDOM DocumentWrapper has been included in the binary JAR file with Saxon-EE and Saxon-PE, but is available only as source code with Saxon-HE (the source code is found in the saxon-resources download).

Comment: The source files can be found here:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.5/.  Look in net/sf/saxon/option/jdom2.